# What can I generically call an "amount" without cents?

Tags: synonyms, money

There is a web application that actively works with money. Inside it, all amounts that are in cents (pennies, sen, etc.) are called "cents" for simplicity. This is necessary, for example, for the names of columns in the database or the names of variables. In general, this is a unification in the project.

Tell me, please, what can you call the amount that is without cents? Provided that the word "amount" cannot be used.

Examples:

- 1,000.00 USD — amount_cents;
- 1,000.00 JPY — amount_cents;
- 1,000 GBP — ?
- 1,000 USD — ?

That is, I repeat, for fractional parts there is (in my opinion) the universal word "cents". Is there such a word for sums without cents?

Comment: The term amount would include the numbers before and after the  dot. So I don’t see the point you are making

Comment: Cent is used in most currencies but not all, so it's no more universal than calling the other column "dollars".

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency) uses the terminology "main currency unit"/"main unit" and "fractional unit" but these don't seem to fit your requirements.

Comment: '... rounded to the nearest pound / hundred dollars / thousand yen ....

Answer (score 2):

The [Wikipedia article for decimalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimalisation) uses the pair "*base/basic unit*" and "*sub-unit*" of currency:

> Decimal currencies have **sub-units** based on a factor of 10. Most **sub-units** are one-100th of the **base currency unit**

> Most countries have decimalised their currencies [...], with one **basic currency unit** and **sub-units** that are to a power of 10, most commonly 100

You could then use:

- 100.15 GBP -> amount_total
- 100 GBP -> amount_base_unit
- .15 GBP -> amount_sub_unit